# Por que AddRange é muito mais rápido que o Add?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Eu estou trabalhando em uma integração de dados entre duas bases, e estou usando *Entity Framework* para isso.

Gerei então o seguinte código, que itera cada registro na tabela Situações da base `dbExterno` e alimenta a minha base `db` :

```
    foreach (var item in dbExterno.Situacoes)
    {
        StatusRecursos statusNew = new StatusRecursos();
        statusNew.Id = item.CodSit;
        statusNew.Nome = item.DesSit;

        db.tTipStatusRecursos.Add(statusNew); //Isso se mostrou muito lento!
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Porém percebi que o código acima estava muito lento, levando minutos para concluir uma interação em cerca de 3000 registros.

Alterei o mesmo então para o código abaixo, e o processo levou segundos.
Nesse segundo código eu ao invés de adicionar cada item ao *context* usando `Add()`, primeiro alimento uma lista genérica de StatusRecursos, e depois adiciono ao contexto usando `AddRange()`.

```
    List<StatusRecursos> listStatus = new List<StatusRecursos>();
    foreach (var item in dbExterno.Situacoes)
    {
        StatusRecursos statusNew = new StatusRecursos();
        statusNew.Id = item.CodSit;
        statusNew.Nome = item.DesSit;
        listStatus.Add(statusNew);  //Não foi lento como o código anterior.
    }
    db.tTipStatusRecursos.AddRange(listStatus); 
    db.SaveChanges();
```

Sei que ficou mais rápido, porém não sei porque adicionar os itens primeiro em uma lista e adicionar ao *context* por `AddRange()` foi tão mais rápido.

Qual é a explicação para isso?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Considerando que você esta usando o *Entity Framework* 6.

O que acontece é que durante o `AddRange()` a checagem automática de alterações é desativada, ao contrário do que acontece com o `Add()`. Tente desativar a checagem e refaça o seu teste usando o `Add()`:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

Você pode encontrar mais detalhes [neste artigo da MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx).

Comment: Realmente, desativando a checagem o `Add` ficou tão rápido quanto o `AddRange`

Answer (score -1):

Não tenho conhecimentos específicos sobre o Entity Framework, mas pelo que posso perceber, o uso de uma operação `AddRange`, ao invés de múltiplas operações `Add` implica em uma performance muito melhor devido ao custo de se realizar operações síncronas em disco.

Devido a forma como discos rígidos funcionam, uma operação de gravação leva um tempo muito maior do que uma operação de gravação na memória RAM. (Um disco rígido opera na escala de tempo de milisegundos, enquanto a RAM opera na escala de tempo de nanosegundos, cerca de 1 milhão de vezes mais rápido)

Esse tempo pode ser considerado como um tipo de *latência*, pois (a grosso modo) independe da quantidade de dados que você está gravando, e é relacionado ao tempo necessário para colocar os dados no barramento (*bus*), enviar os comandos para o disco, posicionar a cabeça de leitura, efetivamente gravar os dados e então receber uma resposta de que os dados foram gravados com sucesso.

As funções `Add` e `AddRange` provavelmente aguardam os dados serem gravados no disco para só depois retornar, pois provavelmente são síncronas. A diferença de tempo entre gravar 1 registro ou 3000 registros em disco provavelmente não é muito significativa, então vale muito mais a pena gravar todos os registros de uma vez do que realizar 3 mil operações.

Uma analogia interessante é a seguinte: Suponha que você tem que mandar 100 pessoas do Rio de Janeiro para São Paulo. Vale muito mais a pena esperar todos embarcarem no mesmo ônibus e fazerem a viajem juntos, do que mandar um por vez, e só mandar o próximo quando receber um telefonema avisando que o anterior já chegou.

A melhoria de performance é ainda mais dramática se envolver comunicação na Rede com um servidor de banco de dados remoto.

Eu recomendo experimentar com diferentes tamanhos de `List<StatusRecursos>` para encontrar o equilibrio ideal de gasto de memória e performance. É possível que a diferença de 1 para 100 registros por vez seja dramática, mas a diferença de 100 para 3000 registros por vez não seja tão significativa. Nesse caso é melhor economizar memória, especialmente se sua aplicação for rodar em plataformas mobile. Uma outra alternativa é verificar se a biblioteca dispõe de funções assíncronas de gravação.

Comment: Entendo seu ponto. O que quis dizer é: Não tenho conhecimentos específicos sobre o Entity Framework, mas já usei outros ORM. Além disso, a pergunta me pareceu geral de ciência de computação, sobre por que armazenar dados em um *buffer* antes de gravar em disco aumenta a performance.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente não tenho muita experiência com a Stack Exchange, tirando algumas poucas perguntas no Stack Overflow em inglês. (Na maior parte do tempo sou um *lurker*) Desculpe pela confusão.

Comment: Eu gostei da sua resposta. Uma pena não ser do contexto da pergunta.